# nginx location match rule, without matching trailing characters

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have the following rule:

```
location /foo {
```

Which matches well for the following examples:

```
mydomain.com/foo
mydomain.com/foo/
mydomain.com/foo/bar?example=true
```

However it is also matching for

```
mydomain.com/foobar
```

I don't want it to match to that last one (/foobar), it should only match if there is either nothing after the foo, or a slash and zero or more characters after it. I've tried **location /foo/ {** but that does not produce desired results either.

Can anyone shed some light on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to handle this, use a regular expression `location` block - or just handle `/foo` separately from `/foo/`.

Regular expression `location` blocks have a different evaluation order and are less efficient than prefix `location` blocks, so my preferred solution is the exact match `location` and prefix `location`.

Generally, `/foo` just redirects to `/foo/`, for example:

```
location = /foo { 
    return 302 /foo/; 
}
location /foo/ {
    ...
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for more.

Answer (score -1):

You can create one Location rule to /foobar whether you need it as an exception:

```
location = /foobar {
    .... 
}
```

Nginx match first URI by = operator.